# Migrating a TCP socket and copying the contents of sk_buff for different queues

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

I am trying to migrate a TCP socket in listening mode from one server to another, to achieve this prupose I am copying multiple parameters related to the tcp_sock, and later I copy the contents of the sk_buff for out-of-order queue, write queue and read queue.

My question is it enough just to copy the following fields of the sk_buff, or not:

```
sk_buff->data
sk_buff->cb
sk_buff->len
sk_buff->data_len
sk_buff->mac_len
sk_buff->hdr_len
sk_buff->csum
sk_buff->priority
sk_buff->ip_summed
sk_buff->pkt_type
sk_buff->rxhash
sk_buff->truesize
```

Or do I need to to copy more extra fields?

For the current implmenetation, copying only these fields work perfectly. But when I try close the socket, the whole machine hangs, so  I suppose. there might be something wrong in the data structure I created in the importing side, and I still need more fields to fill.

**The current Linux Kernel Version I am developing on is 3.8.29**

Comment: Just to be clear - you are trying to dynamically migrate TCP state from one machine to another?

Comment: Yes, in a dynamic way.

Comment: Well, that's err..  'brave'.